# ASP.NET DateTime and datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a little problem. First I have this datepicker:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#engReq").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<p>
<label for="engReq">Engineering Request:</label>
<input type="text" id="engReq" name="engReq" class="form-control" required />
</p>
```

And I am trying to pass this value from my ASP.NET Controller to Class like so

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic Post([FromBody]AirportDataClass airportData)
{

      airportData.insertData(airportData);
}
```

Class:

```
public class AirportDataClass
    {
        public string job_no { get; set; }
        public DateTime EngineeringReq { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnginerringRec { get; set; }
        public string AppForms { get; set; }
        public string Cheque { get; set; }
        public string ReadyToSubmit { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeficiencyReq { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeficiencyResp { get; set; }

        public void insertData(AirportDataClass airportData)
        {
        }

    }
```

but when I put a breaking point on public void insertData and checkout airportData this date is returned and not the date from datepicker: 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM, expected date is the date from the datepicker - example: 08/01/2014 what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you expecting `engReq` to be translated to `EngineeringReq`? (I'd also strongly recommend not abbreviating whatever `Req` and `Rec` are short for... they're very similar at the moment...)

Comment: you are right, my bad

Comment: How about this 
`var dateSelected = $('#<%= engReq.ClientId %>').val();`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a proper view, the MVC model builder does not know that you want some random HTML input control mapped to a specific property on your model. If you use the razor engine and strongly typed views, you can use HTML helpers like HTML.editor for which will render out the correct HTML and then they will match automatically to the correct properties on your model. Your jquery datepicker will work just fine with the HTML rendered by the razor view engine.